# C#: Most effective way to select the text of a subitem in a listview?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, selecteditem

Trying to work with the content of a single subitem from a listview. What is the best way to go about selecting the value? I've tried using ListViewItem.SubItems[2].ToString(), output isn't quite what I'm looking for.

Essentially Listview had 3 columns, I want to work with the value of the text in the 3rd column of the ListView's Selected Item. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You want [ListViewSubItem.Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitem.text.aspx), not ToString().

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, ended up going with:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text);
```